# Input redirection with Java via windows command line

Tags: java, algorithm, ide

I have recently started the Princeton algorithms course (available on coursera) but I’m running into issues with the choice of an IDE and input redirection. Princeton recommends using their Dr Java IDE, but this does not support input redirection, which is required pretty regularly. I can still write and compile programs in that IDE, and then run them from the command line (I’m using windows), which is the route the authors appear to recommend. However all of their programs make use of their StdLib.jar file. Compiling the program is fine (the IDE settings can reference the necessary JAR) but it seems that each time I want to run a program with input redirection (which is VERY common in the book and course) I would need to type ***java -cp .;algs4.jar calcAverage < input.txt***. This seems like unnecessary repetition, and the book is loaded with command line examples that would simply say ***java  calcAverage < input.txt***. Is there not a way to avoid constant setting of the class path?

Note, I'm aware that I could potentially use another IDE, but what bothers me is that I suspect I've missunderstood something.

Comment: I read Sedgewicks algorithms book and used intellij. It's a lot easier to use an ide for java, because it's verbose and autocompletion helps a lot. Also, I did not use their libraries, I think they are not that important.